# How to add a custom ModelMetadataDetailsProvider that has a dependency that needs to be resolved by Autofac?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm trying to add a custom ModelMetadataDetailsProvider, but the provider implementation has dependencies that need to be resolved by the Service Provider (Autofac). If I Add the ModelMetadataDetailsProvider in ConfigureServices, I have to instantiate and manually provide all of the dependencies, some of which are singleton and are AutoActivated, so that won't work... Is it possible to add a ModelMetadataDetailsProvider outside of ConfigureServices?

It doesn't appear that this can be configured using DI, so the only thing I can think of is to use the Service Locator Anti Pattern to provide the dependencies when they are needed instead of in the constructor. Is there a more acceptable way to accomplish this?

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc()
          .AddMvcOptions(options => {
             options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new MyProvider(???))
          })
          .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
          .AddControllersAsServices();

  services.AddAutofac();

  ApplicationContainer = BuildContainer(services);

  return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);
}

public IContainer BuildContainer(IServiceCollection services)
{
  var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
  builder.Populate(services);

  builder.RegisterType<HttpContextAccessor>()
      .As<IHttpContextAccessor>()
      .SingleInstance();

  builder.RegisterType<DataAccess>()
      .As<IDataAccess>()
      .WithParameter("connectionString", Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseContext"))
      .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

   ....

   builder.RegisterType<D1>()
      .As<ID1>();

   builder.RegisterType<D2>()
      .As<ID2>();

   builder.RegisterType<D3>()
      .As<ID3>();

   builder.RegisterType<MyProvider>()
      .As<IMyProvider>();
 }



public interface IMyProvider : IDisplayMetadataProvider
{
  ...
}

public class MyProvider : IMyProvider
{
    public MyProvider (ID1 d1, ID2 d2, ID3 d3)
    {
      ...
    }

    public void CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a class that implements the `IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>` interface:

```cs
public class AddCustomModelMetadataDetailsProvider : IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>
{
    private readonly MyCustomModelMetadataDetailsProvider _provider;

    public AddCustomModelMetadataDetailsProvider(MyCustomModelMetadataDetailsProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public void Configure(MvcOptions options)
    {
        options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(_provider);
    }
}
```

and register it as such in the `Configure` method:

```cs
services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>, AddCustomModelMetadataDetailsProvider>();
```

The benefit of this approach, as you can see, is that you can use regular constructor injection in the `AddCustomModelMetadataDetailsProvider` class to get the instance of the service you're interested in.

ASP.NET automatically calls the `Configure` methods of all the `IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>` services registered in the container.

---

Because creating these classes can be time-consuming, ASP.NET Core 2.2 introduced new overloads which allow you to do the following:

```cs
services
    .AddOptions<MvcOptions>()
    .Configure<MyCustomModelMetadataDetailsProvider>((options, customMetadataDetailsProvider) =>
    {
         options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(customMetadataDetailsProvider);
    });
```

In that case, `customMetadataDetailsProvider` would be resolved from the container.

You can include up to 5 services to configure your options. See this [official documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configuretoptions-tdep1--tdep4-method).

Comment: I went with the ASP.NET Core 2.2 method you mentioned and it works flawlessly!